# How to rewrite this Oracle Query to hibernate Query?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

i wrote this query in oracle specific

`Student_Master` have these fields `stud_id,stud_name`. 
`Student_detail` have `course_id,course_name,cou_stud_id` and so on.

I need to select records from both table in case `student_detail` table of `cou_stud_id` null or empty means to select all matched records of this condition.

```
SELECT stud_id,stud_name,course_name ,course_id FROM STUDENT_MASTER,STUDENT_DETAIL WHERE stud_id(+)=cou_stud_id.
```

How can i write to HQL Query?
This is My Original scenario 
i have two hbm files ADVMAgencyMaster.hbm.xml,ADVRoheader.hbm.xml corresponding pojo classes are  ADVMAgencyMaster.java,ADVroheader.java.

Match records from both table that condition is MAMAID(+)=TROHAMAID in oracle.Pls tell how writer in HQL

Comment: It is meaningless to discuss without knowing how you are mapping the tables to your entities.  Once you have properly mapped to your entities (including the relationships), this should be a very basic use of HQL that you should have learned from any Hibernate introduction material.

Comment: Explain how to use left outer join that is (+) in oracle and HQL.MyMapping are working perfectly.stud_id is primary and co_stu_id refer as foreignkey.

Comment: @karthik.A.M please check, if your mapping is ok , your objective is not a big deal.. even a small R&D over Google might help u out as well.

Comment: @karthik.A.M O-R Mapping is more than corresponds a table to an entity and corresponds each column to a field.  Obviously you are still having a deficit mapping

Comment: Query qry=Session.createQuery("SELECT SM.stud_id,SM.stud_name,SD.course_name ,SD.course_id FROM STUDENT_MASTER SM LEFT JOIN SM.STUDENT_DETAIL SD WHERE SM.stud_id=SD.cou_stud_id "). In this STUDENT_MASTER,STUDENT_DETAIL are bean class of corresponding table

Comment: SELECT SM.stud_id,SM.stud_name,SD.course_name ,SD.course_id FROM STUDENT_MASTER SM LEFT JOIN SM.STUDENT_DETAIL SD ON SM.stud_id=SD.cou_stud_id .. ( On Clause missing in you comment query )

Answer (score 0):

This might help u out , it will find all students with or without detail.

```
from Student_Master SM Left Join Student_detail SD on SM.stud_id = SD.cou_stud_id
Where SM.stud_id = (student_id to filter)
```

And if you have properly Mapped your both class in Hibernate Using ( `@OneToOne or @OnetoMany Relationship` ) , you can easily get detail with respect to student object.

Comment: in this ON is Undefined keyword it throw an error

Comment: @karthik.A.M ON is a keyword in most of sql languages

Comment: @karthik.A.M please show your exception or error!

Comment: i am writing this query in HQL

Comment: Sorry, throws an Exception ,ON is undefined KEYWORD

Comment: That's what I said in my comment: your relationship should be properly mapped too.

Comment: Give any possible  solution for this type of condition

Comment: @karthik.A.M if you looking for solution only just Replace Student_Master and Student_detail With respective table names and properties with Fields in Tables Columns and Append Select * ... you will get the output but it will be raw sql, as i feel you have not mapped the Database tables properly with hibernate using annotations else my hql will output the required data

Comment: @karthik.A.M can you post your Student_master and Student_Details Hbm file or pojo with annotations,so i can checkout the problem in mapping if any!

Comment: sir my table struture is too many columns in our project.Just i said example of two table.can i post whole things na it will get more difficult for U.

Comment: @karthik.A.M  dear just post down you hbm with requried columns that can help us form relationship :)

Comment: Briefly tell how can i select particular fields from table using HQL

Comment: @karthik.A.M selecting in hibernate is as simple as selecting in Sql, a small change is that , in sql we use columns/fields in select query where as in hql we use corresponding properties of class. thats it. Simple :)

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan I post hbm and pojo class .If u know means tell how to write this condition

Comment: @karthik.A.M where is pojo or hbm file u posted ? :s

Comment: sir it doesn't show.How can i post this coding.In my edit list,show coding after i saved it doesn't appear.

Comment: @karthik.A.M post it in your Question section!

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan  i posted question in the title of "JOINS WITH CONDITONS IN hibernate".kindly find the question and tell solution sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add to your entity Student_Master an object studentDetail, so the query becomes:

```
from Student_Master SM 
Left Join fetch SM.studentDetail.cou_stud_id
Where SM.stud_id = (student_id to filter)
```